# Why agents disappeared from Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I integrated the dialogflow agent with Google Assistante and started the alpha version for testing, and after that all my agents disappeared from Dialogflow. There are no agents in the list of agents. I did not delete them. What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is quite unclear. please see [ask] to reformulate a more specific question, that will maximizes the chance to get a valuable feedback

Comment: Hi, please follow GCP status page for more info https://status.cloud.google.com

Answer (score 2):

Google is reporting a technical outage with accessing agents and data in the Dialogflow console. It will be fixed quickly I'm sure (it's Google).
Please check the status [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/)