# Dialogflow Agents/Projects Disappeared automatically

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have multiple agents created with Dialogflow and many of them are live in Production. However, suddenly the Dialogflow projects disappeared and now I see only the option to create a new agent.

However, I see that Production Agents are working fine. I verified it through the app that I created which is connected to Dialogflow API.

[image]

Comment: The account you logged in could be changed. Can you check your account detail if it is right one or not?

Comment: Yes, it is the right account.

Comment: I think this is the same issue reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561120/dialogflow-agent-disappeared).

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal I faced same issue just after responded you. It disappears and comes back.

Comment: My agents disappeared too but, they didn't come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google cloud status dashboard is reporting that the problem has been solved. I checked my agents and they came back.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me today, then I accessed after some time and they were back, but when I tried to work on an agent after a bit it gave error and all the agents disappeared again. I think they may be having server issues?

Comment: You should give your views in comments not in answers. It will help other people searching for the answers.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I wanted to comment but it wouldn't let me do it since I don't have enough reputation points

Comment: Hi, please follow GCP status page for more info status.cloud.google.com

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new Agent and the agent that disappeared came back.

Answer (score 0):

please follow GCP status page for more info status.cloud.google.com